# AD/LDAP: "Invalid Username/Password" after click button login

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

Currently, I  do the login page. This login page needs authentication from Active Directory (AD). Thus, I use LDAP Method. Although I enter the correct username and password, It still shows the message "Invalid username or password".

And below is the basic php code.

home.php

```
   <html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body{
                text-align:center;
                }
            form{
                margin: 0 auto; width:500px;
                }
            input{
                padding: 10px; font-size: 20px;
                }
        </style>
    </head>
        <body>
        <h1>Authentication</h1>
            <form action="ldap.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="username" /><br><br>
                <input type="password" name="password" /><br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" /><br>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html
```

ldap.php

```
    <?php

        $ldap_dn = "uid=".$_POST["username"].",CN=TG Work Flow,OU=New User,DC=topglove,DC=tg,DC=local";
        $ldap_password = $_POST["password"];

        $ldap_con = ldap_connect("ldap://172.16.10.43:389");
        ldap_set_option($ldap_con, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

        if(@ldap_bind($ldap_con,$ldap_dn,$ldap_password))
            echo "Authenticated";
        else
            echo "Invalid Credential";
    ?>
```

Comment: This is the LDAP requirement

LDAP URL -->  ldap://172.xx.xx.xx:xx
ADMIN USER -->  CN=TG Work Flow,OU=New User,DC=topglove,DC=tg,DC=local
ADMIN PASSWORD --> admin123
USER BASE DN  -->  DC=topglove,DC=tg,DC=local

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how you are building `$ldap_dn`. Distinguished Names for accounts always start with `CN=`. AD doesn't use `uid`, like other LDAP implementations might.

But the account's DN is not guaranteed to be `CN=username` either. The "username" is the `sAMAccountName` attribute in AD.

The fact is, at this point, you don't know what the DN for the account is. But the good news is that you don't need to know. AD allows you to authentication with just the username, however, you might need to include the domain name.

Try this:

```
 $ldap_dn = $_POST["username"]
```

or this (replace `DOMAIN` with your domain name):

```
 $ldap_dn = "DOMAIN\\".$_POST["username"]
```

Comment: And if you want people to be able to log in with something else than the sAMAccountName (for example their email) you can do an LDAP-Search with a spechail account to find the user, then get the users DN from that result and then do the bind with that DN and the password. Find an example at https://gist.github.com/heiglandreas/5689592

Comment: @Gabriel Luci. Thanks for the help !!! I really appreciate it. Voted!